# What is the best choice of temperature for Ising model, and parallel tempering?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, ising-model

- How can I determine the critical temperature for the Ising model?
- How can I determine the optimal timing for parallel tempering to occur and the appropriate gap between each swap?
- During parallel tempering for the Ising model, should I terminate the parallel tempering after a certain number of steps if I am solely interested in the zero energy state?

I am concerned that if I continue parallel tempering for too long, the zero energy state (0 temperature) may not have sufficient time to manifest. As a result, when I terminate the simulation, I might obtain results associated with a different temperature. For instance, if parallel tempering occurs just one step before I end the simulation, it could potentially provide an inaccurate representation of the true zero energy state.